# A Geometric Proof of $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}6$? (and other integer inputs for the Zeta)

Tags: sequences-and-series, alternative-proof, zeta-functions

Is there a known geometric proof for this famous problem? $$\zeta(2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2}=\frac16\pi^2$$

Moreover we can consider possibilities of geometric proofs of the following identity for positive even inputs of the Zeta function:
$$ \zeta(2n)=(-1)^{n+1} \frac{B_{2n}(2\pi)^{2n}}{2(2n)!}$$
and negative inputs:
$$ \zeta(-n)=-\frac{B_{n+1}}{n+1}$$

Comment: There are many nice proofs at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n2 . Is one of them geometric enough for you? (David Speyer's answer might fit the bill.)

Comment: Here's a proof by Prof. Greene at UCLA: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~greene/How%20Geometry.pdf

Comment: thank you Qiaochu one of them is ;)

Comment: I wanted to ask this question some time ago. I'm glad to see it posted. (I thought of an elementary geometrical proof)

Comment: do you mean that you have an elementary geometric proof? Would you mind sharing it?

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1284161/

Comment: On behalf of @Kazi Abu Rousan: This is a link to an answer...due to insufficient reputation point I can't post it in comment... http://enotepro.com/?p=77 There you will find the proof of Bessel problem using the Inverse Pythagoras theorem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is a geometric proof for $\zeta(2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2}=\frac16\pi^2$, and, on top of that, it is a very unusual and, in my opinion, beautiful one.

In his gorgeous paper ["How to compute  $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ by solving triangles"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701039), Mikael Passare offers this idea for proving $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$:

[image]

Proof of equality of square and curved areas is based on another picture:

[image]

Recapitulation of Passare's proof using formulas is as follows: (for each step there is a geometric justification)

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-nx}}{n}\; dx\; = -\int_0^\infty log(1-e^{-x})\; dx\; = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what you mean by a geometric proof, but the following should fit the bill, as here the identity is deduced from a comparison of two areas: the first area is

$\displaystyle\int_{[0,1]^2} \frac{1}{1 - xy} \frac{dx dy}{\sqrt{xy}}$

and the second is

$4 \displaystyle \int_{\substack{\xi, \eta>0 \\ \xi \eta \leq 1}} \frac{ d \xi \, d \eta}{(1+\xi^2)(1+\eta^2)}$;

They are equal by a change of variables. For the first quantity, expand $(1-xy)^{-1}$ as a geometric series and integrate term-wise to get $3 \cdot \zeta(2)$. The second can be computed to $\pi^2/2$. This can be found in detail in Kontsevich and Zagier's [*Periods*](http://www.ihes.fr/~maxim/TEXTS/Periods.pdf) (bottom of page 8), where they attribute the idea to Calabi. (You should easily be able to hunt down an identity of $\zeta (n)$ being equal to an integral over the unit square in $\mathbb{R}^n$, like the first above. It might be a fun exercise to see if this idea is can be adapted for even $n$.)

Answer (score 3):

One geometric/probabilistic proof is by Eugenio Calabi.

Consider the double integral $$I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1-x^2y^2} \ dy \ dx.$$ Expand the integrand into a geometric series as such $$ \frac{1}{1-x^2y^2} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (xy)^{2n},$$ which is justified by the region of integration, that is $0<x,y<1.$ Exchange summation and integration (application of Tonelli's theorem), and integrate term by term to get $$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}.$$ Now, we evaluate $I$ directly. Make the change of variables $$x=\frac{\sin(u)}{\cos(v)}, y=\frac{\sin(v)}{\cos(u)}.$$ This transformation has Jacobian Determinant $$\frac{\partial (x,y) }{\partial(u,v)}=1-x^2y^2,$$ which cancels with the integrand, and the region becomes the open triangle defined by the inequalities $$u+v<\frac{\pi}{2}, u, v>0$$ We know from geometry that this triangle has base $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and height $\frac{\pi}{2},$ hence the area is $\frac{\pi^2}{8}.$ Hence $I=\frac{\pi^2}{8}.$ Now to obtain $\zeta(2),$ we use the fact that $$\zeta(2)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)^2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2},$$ which implies by some algebraic manipulation that

$$\zeta(2)=\frac{4}{3}I=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

We can extend this proof to the $\zeta(2k).$  Let

$$I_{2k}= \int_{0}^{1}... \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1-x_1^2 \dots x_{2k}^2} \ dx_{2k} \ ... \ dx_1.$$

Converting this integrand into a geometric series and exchanging summation and integration gives the sum:
$$I_{2k}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2k}}.$$ We can then recover
$$\zeta(2k)=\frac{2^{2k}}{2^{2k}-1} I_{2k},$$ by observing 
$$\zeta(2k)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)^{2k}} + I_{2k},$$ and using some algebraic manipulation.

On the other hand, we make the change of variables $$x_i=\frac{\sin(u_i)}{\cos(u_{i+1})}, 1 \leq i \leq 2k,$$ and $u_{2k+1}:=u_{1}$ here. This transformation turns out to have a Jacobian Determinant which cancels with the denominator of the integrand in $I_{2k}.$ The region of integration becomes the open polytope:
$$\Delta^{2k}= \left \lbrace (u_1, \dots, u_{2k}): u_{i}+u_{i+1} < \frac{\pi}{2}, u_i>0, 1 \leq i \leq 2k \right \rbrace$$ in which $u_{2k+1}:=u_1.$ 
Computing the volume of this polytope is much more difficult. Rescaling with the change of variables $u_i=\frac{\pi}{2} v_i,$ and letting $V_1, \dots, V_{2k}$ being $2k$ independent, uniformly distributed random variables on $(0,1),$ we get

> > $$I_{2k}=\text{Vol}(\Delta^{2k})=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2k} \text{Pr} \left( V_1+V_2<1, \dots, V_{2k-1}+V_{2k}<1, V_{2k}+V_{1}<1 \right),$$ the probability that $V_1, \dots, V_{2k}$ have *cyclically pairwise consecutive* sums less than $1.$

In the literature, the aforementioned probability has been computed in several ways (see: 
https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/news/Elkies.pdf
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.3602.pdf
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/35be/01e63c0bfd32b82c97d58ccc9c35471c3617.pdf)

**Joshua Seaton** also mentioned Zagier's and Kontsevich's reproduced Calabi proof. The general version of this is to evaluate

$$J_{2k}= \int_{0}^{1}... \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1 \dots x_{2k}}(1-x_1 \dots x_{2k})}\ dx_{2k} \ ... \ dx_1.$$

A quick substitution shows $J_{2k}=2^{2k}I_{2k}.$ The generalized version of the change of variables is

$$x_i=\frac{\xi_i^2(1+\xi_{i+1}^2)}{1+\xi_i^2}, \dots, x_{2k}=\frac{\xi_{2k}^2(1+\xi_{1}^2)}{1+\xi_{2k}^2},$$ and upon computing its Jacobian Determinant, we get that

$$J_{2k}=\int_{\mathbb{H}^{2k}} \frac{1}{\xi_1^2+1} \dots \frac{1}{\xi_{2k}^2+1}  \ d \xi_{1} \dots d \xi_{2k},$$ where $\mathbb{H}^{2k}$ is the hyperbolic defined by the inequalities:
$$\xi_{i}\xi_{i+1} <1, \xi_i>0,$$ where $1 \leq i \leq 2k$ and $\xi_{2k+1}:=\xi_1.$ Letting $\Xi_1, \dots \Xi_{2k}$ be $2k$ independent, nonnegative Cauchy random variables, we get

> > $$I_{2k}=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2k} \text{Pr} \left( \Xi_1\Xi_2<1, \dots, \Xi_{2k-1}\Xi_{2k}<1, \Xi_{2k}\Xi_{1}<1 \right),$$ the probability that $\Xi_1, \dots, \Xi_{2k}$ have *cyclically pairwise consecutive* products less than $1.$

In my paper, I show that the probabilities lead to a very gargantuan formula:

> > $$I_{2k}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2k}}= \left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right)^{2k} +\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right)^{2k}  \sum_{n=1}^{k} \sum_{\substack{(r_1, \dots, r_n) \in [2k]^n: \\ |r_p-r_q| \notin \lbrace 0,1,2k-1 \rbrace, \\ p,q \in [n]} } \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i+\sum_{j=1}^{i} \alpha_j},$$ 
> >     where $[m]:= \lbrace 1, \dots, m \rbrace$ and 
> >     $$\alpha_j=2- \delta(2k,2) - \sum_{m=1}^{j-1} \delta(|r_m-r_j|,2)+\delta(|r_m-r_j|,2k-2)$$ and $\delta(a,b)$ is the *Kronecker Delta Function*. In particular, the inner sum is taken over all *tuples* $(r_1, \dots, r_n) \in [k]^
> > n$ having *cyclically pairwise nonconsecutive* entries.