# Seeking possibility of more elementary means of evaluating an improper integral.

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals, taylor-expansion, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

It can be shown that $\int_0^\infty -\log{(1-e^{-x})}=\zeta(2)$ by expanding out the integral as $\log(1-z)$, exchanging summation and integration, then summing up the integrals. I am wondering if there are means to prove this that do not require such advanced tools.

This integral also represents the area bound by the axes and the curve $e^{-x}+e^{-y}=1$, in case that fact is of any assistance.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1432348/97236) (or rather [here](http://mathcircle.berkeley.edu/archivedocs/2009_2010/lectures/0910lecturespdf/Basel.pdf)) for a geometric idea of your steps (due to Passare).

Comment: I don't really see what "advanced tools" you are using here. Both Taylor expansion of $\log$ and summation-integration exchange are elementary steps.

Comment: They are out of the HSC syllabus.

Answer (score 3):

The two approaches that come to mind both use the power series for $-\log(1-x)$.

**First Approach:** Use the power series for $-\log(1-x)$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty-\log\left(1-e^{-x}\right)\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-kx}}k\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k\int_0^\infty e^{-kx}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\\[6pt]
&=\zeta(2)
\end{align}
$$
**Second Approach:** Substitute $u=e^{-x}$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty-\log\left(1-e^{-x}\right)\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\frac{-\log\left(1-u\right)}u\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{u^{k-1}}k\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k\int_0^1u^{k-1}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\\[6pt]
&=\zeta(2)
\end{align}
$$
Both seem pretty elementary.